# Trying (but failing) to Test-Path with a string

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Basically, I've set a variable and I want to check if the file exists.  If it doesn't, it needs to be created.  I think I'm having trouble with the variable or the string value...I'm not exactly sure.  In any case, it worked once!  After it was created, I tested it by deleting the file.  The script never prompted me to recreate the file...

```
# Setting up a few variables
$SysAdmin = "MyDomain\MyUser"
$StudentID = Read-Host "Enter the Student ID you wish to look up."
$ADDC = "AD04"
$HashedPassword = "$env:USERPROFILE\OneDrive\tier-2_pass.txt"

# Checking for a text file with a hashed password and creating it if it's not found.
If (-Not (Test-Path $HashedPassword)) {
    $SecretPassword = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter a secret password"
    $SecretPassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "$HashedPassword"
    }

# Getting the hashed password from the text file.
$Password = Get-Content $HashedPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $SysAdmin,$Password

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ADDC -Credential $Creds { Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter { Pager -eq $Using:StudentID } | Select-Object -Property Name, DisplayName, SamAccountName, @{Name = "Student ID"; Expression = {$_.Pager}}, @{Name = "Possible Location-1"; Expression = {$_.Office}}, @{Name = "Possible Location-2"; Expression = {$_.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName}} | FL }
```

So, that's the script....  I see no errors unless I do a `Get-Content` against the `$HashedPassword` variable...at which point it lets me know the file is indeed gone.  What am I missing?

Comment: what error are u getting?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors where I'd expect to see them.  It jumps right to the final line of code (`Invoke-Command...`) which fails because there's no password file to read from.  So, it's the typical `Get-Content : Cannot find path...`

Comment: have you checked the location to make sure the file isnt already created?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned earlier, I tested it via deleting the file.  So, I know the file is gone.  Obviously, if it were there, we wouldn't be seeing the `Get-Content` error I just mentioned.

Comment: can you try another path then onedrive for troubleshooting perpose?

Comment: Why dont you debug the if loop? looks like it is skipping the if loop.

Comment: Rohin, I feel the same way; I don't think it's processing the `if` loop but it's not showing any errors there.  So, I don't know where to look at that section...

Comment: ArcSet, I just tried another path and it never prompted me to create the TXT file so, again, I think the `IF` loop isn't being handled correctly.

Comment: I think I fixed it!  I just kept messing with it...  I'm not entirely sure what I did but it seems to have worked - whatever I did.